# How to configure systemd $PATH to match user $PATH

Tags: linux, deployment, virtual-machine, systemd, pyenv

I run a Next.js frontend on a VM using systemd. My workflow for making systemd services is usually:

1. Make the application work from the user shell (`ec2-user` in this case)
2. Write a unit file which does the same, and uses the same user

However, the service did not work as expected, due to differences in `$PATH`.

Indeed, `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` contain code that extends `$PATH`. This configuration has been done automatically by tools like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

So I ended up making an ugly unit file to match the same `$PATH` that I have in my user shell:

```
[Unit]
Description=Web App Frontend
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/bin:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin"
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/web-app-frontend
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/yarn start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Is there a cleaner way to solve this?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Please delete this.

Comment: Got it. Moved it over there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767709/how-to-configure-systemd-path-to-match-user-path/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want your systemd service to have the same environment as when you open a termina. You can achieve this using PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) to load the user's environment.
Just add `PAMName=login` to your `.service` fle. Like this :

```
[Service]
PAMName=login
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/your/command
```

This will enables your systemd load envirment using PAM login module.